# How to Add uirevision Directly to Figure in Plotly Dash for Automatic Updates

Tags: python, plotly

I have a Plotly figure built in Python that updates automatically. I want to preserve dashboard zooms even with automatic updates. The documentation in Plotly says this can be done using the layout `uirevision` field, per the [this community writeup](https://community.plotly.com/t/preserving-ui-state-like-zoom-in-dcc-graph-with-uirevision-with-dash/15793). The docs give this as an example of the return dictionary:

```py
 return {
        'data': data,
        'layout': {
            # `uirevsion` is where the magic happens
            # this key is tracked internally by `dcc.Graph`,
            # when it changes from one update to the next,
            # it resets all of the user-driven interactions
            # (like zooming, panning, clicking on legend items).
            # if it remains the same, then that user-driven UI state
            # doesn't change.
            # it can be equal to anything, the important thing is
            # to make sure that it changes when you want to reset the user
            # state.
            #
            # in this example, we *only* want to reset the user UI state
            # when the user has changed their dataset. That is:
            # - if they toggle on or off reference, don't reset the UI state
            # - if they change the color, then don't reset the UI state
            # so, `uirevsion` needs to change when the `dataset` changes:
            # this is easy to program, we'll just set `uirevision` to be the
            # `dataset` value itself.
            #
            # if we wanted the `uirevision` to change when we add the "reference"
            # line, then we could set this to be `'{}{}'.format(dataset, reference)`
            'uirevision': dataset,

            'legend': {'x': 0, 'y': 1}
        }
    }
```

However, my figure is built more like this:

```py
import plotly.express as px

@app.callback(
    Output("graph", "figure"),
    [Input("interval-component", "n_intervals")])
def display_graph(n_intervals):
    # Logic for obtaining data/processing is not shown
    my_figure = px.line(my_data_frame, x=my_data_frame.index, y=['line_1', 'line_2'], 
    title='Some Title', template='plotly_dark')
    return my_figure
```

In other words, **since I am not returning a dictionary, but a plotly express figure directly, how can I directly access the uirevision value so that UI changes from the user are preserved?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the figure dictionary, which can be accessed like so:

```
my_figure['layout']['uirevision'] = 'some_value'
```

This can also be used to access other useful aspects of the figure, such as changing the line color of a specific line entry:

```py
my_figure['data'][2]['line']['color'] = '#FFFF00'
```

To see the other entry options, print out `my_figure` in a Python session.

Note: since the `uirevision` option isn't documented very well (at least, not in my searching online), I thought it worth posting this as an option.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `update_layout` member function of the figure.

```
my_figure.update_layout(uirevision=<your data>)
```

More information here: https://plotly.com/python/creating-and-updating-figures/#updating-figure-layouts